# PayPal webhook did not receive any events

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

I created a PayPal plus Payment in my website. I can choose a payment methode and I can pay.
I have also created a PayPal webhook. The webhook works. I tested it in the webhook simulator.

The problem is: if I pay i receive nothing in my webhook.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you need to Subscribe to Events by providing your webhook URLs PayPal; note that this is completely separate from testing in the simulator. See: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/rest-webhooks/#subscribe-to-events

Comment: Hello Sam,

thanks for your answer. My webhook is already registered.

Jan

Comment: have you guys solved this issue? I'm also not receiving any notifications for REST app. I have set the webhook

Comment: I have the same issue.I registered a webhook in the paypal developer website. The webhook simulator works and i get a post request. But if i create a subscription like in the example:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/master/rest-api-sample/src/main/java/com/paypal/api/sample/SubscriptionSample.java
I do not get the event. I am a bit confused. Is this part neccesary: 
context.addConfiguration(Constants.PAYPAL_WEBHOOK_ID, "mycreatedWebHookId");
or 
merchantPreferences.setReturnUrl("which url")
merchantPreferences.setNotifyUrl("which url?");